# Hide Some Categories in Post Editor

Tags: categories, block-editor, post-editor

I run a multi author blog. I want authors not to be able to publish posts under some categories(Suppose ‘selected’, ‘editorial’). So I want to hide them in post editor.

I tried this code:

```
add_filter('list_terms_exclusions', 'yoursite_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2);
function yoursite_list_terms_exclusions( $exclusions, $args ) {
  global $pagenow;
  if (in_array($pagenow,array('post.php','post-new.php')) && 
     !current_user_can('manage_options')) {
    $exclusions = " {$exclusions} AND t.slug NOT IN ('selected','editorial')";
  }
  return $exclusions;
}
```

But it is not working. I used this code too:

```
function hide_categories_for_specific_user( $exclusions, $args ){    
if (!current_user_can('manage_options') ) {    
   // IDs of terms to be excluded
   $exclude_array = array("5","6"); // CHANGE THIS TO IDs OF YOUR TERMS    
   // Generation of exclusion SQL code
   $exterms = wp_parse_id_list( $exclude_array );
   foreach ( $exterms as $exterm ) {
           if ( empty($exclusions) )
                   $exclusions = ' AND ( t.term_id <> ' . intval($exterm) . ' ';
           else
                   $exclusions .= ' AND t.term_id <> ' . intval($exterm) . ' ';
   }    
   // Closing bracket
   if ( !empty($exclusions) )
       $exclusions .= ')';    
   // Return our SQL statement
   return $exclusions;    
  }
}    
 // Finally hook up our filter
 add_filter( 'list_terms_exclusions', 'hide_categories_for_specific_user', 10, 2 );
```

It works in the post editor but it breaks category widget in the front-end for non-admin users.

I used several plugins for that. “Restrict Categories, Author category” etc. But no luck. I am currently hiding them using css :nth-of-type. But works for add new post but it breaks when authors edit their post.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: There's several post editors, which one are you talking about? The classic editor? Block editor? Page builder plugin? Have you considered that the categories you want to hide might be better off as a custom taxonomy? Then you could declare it requires capabilities that are higher than authors, and it'd have its own UI, and even give you the option of their own template archives if that's what you want. There's no need to repurpose categories to do multiple jobs

Comment: block editor. I don't need Custom taxonomy as I want posts of these two categories to show up in blog with others posts.

Comment: a custom taxonomy doesn't prevent posts showing up, I don't see how it would change that, but I don't have much information about your situation so I can't advise

Comment: So this filter might not do what you want it to do, it isn't an SQL filter, but rather it filters the `WP_Term_Query` parameter for `NOT IN`. It'll have a major performance hit as a result, but it might also prevent posts that authors use from ever being able to have those terms, even if an admin sets them it would be unset when the author saves their post. It will also erase their existence for users that aren't administrators, so logged out users can't view those terms and they won't appear in lists. What do the editorial and selected terms do?